# Data Objects in Business Logic Layer when using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, n-tier-architecture

Do I need to write classes that represent database tables when I am using Entity Framework? For example, I have the following tables: Account, Customer, Order,... Entity Framework will provide me with Account, Customer, Order objects in addition to the object set of: Accounts, Orders, Customers .. etc. Now do I need to wrap these objects or not?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your requirements, i may simply say "No".
EF generates all domain objects, and represents your tables with objectsets.

Answer (score 0):

EF generates an object representation of table entities. But it is not the same as domain object.

Application should operate with domain objects, not EF object.

I think that writing concrete domain classes is good idea. But is complex way, and in some cases it adds an unnecessary layer of complexity.

Another way is using EF CodeFirst, for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.

Comment: I am going old style, so I am using Database first method. I am not familiar with the term Domain Object but it presume that it means wrapping the classes with another classes. Anyway, I do not see the point of adding the extra layer of complexity. On the other hand, removing such classes will mean that my Presentation layer will speak directly with entity framework and in the presentation layer will be in direct contact with data access layer which should be forbidden.

Comment: You should choose between using data access objects directly from presentation layer, that is not good idea at all or building one more layer between presentation layer and data access layer with more accurate meaning of `business object` and mappings between `data objects` and `business objects`.